# opencv cmake not building

Tags: terminal, macos, macports

I've been trying to build OpenCV in a mac (Yosemite 10.10) using cmake-gui and the compilers gcc,g++ and gfortran given by MacPorts. 
I HAVE to use those compilers. 
I configured WITH_OPENCL to be OFF and generated the binaries. But when I try to make it in the terminal I get the following error :

```
[ 65%] Building CXX object modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_features2d.dir/src/fast.cpp.o
/Users/imecindia/Desktop/Downloaded Libraries/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/features2d/src/fast.cpp: In function 'bool cv::ocl_FAST(cv::InputArray, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, int, bool, int)':
/Users/imecindia/Desktop/Downloaded Libraries/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/features2d/src/fast.cpp:267:53: error: 'fast_oclsrc' is not a member of 'cv::ocl::features2d'
 ocl::Kernel fastKptKernel("FAST_findKeypoints", ocl::features2d::fast_oclsrc);
                                                 ^
/Users/imecindia/Desktop/Downloaded Libraries/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/features2d/src/fast.cpp:305:60: error: 'fast_oclsrc' is not a member of 'cv::ocl::features2d'
     ocl::Kernel fastNMSKernel("FAST_nonmaxSupression", ocl::features2d::fast_oclsrc);
                                                        ^
make[2]: *** [modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_features2d.dir/src/fast.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/features2d/CMakeFiles/opencv_features2d.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I do not know why I'm receiving this error. Is there some other configuration I should be doing? Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Given your openCV is a beta could it be that it has not been tested - does a release version work (and as a beta I suspect off topic here)

Comment: I tried with release versions as well. Same issue.

Comment: Try the macports port as the porter will have dealt with any issues - as you are already using macports this should not be too much issue. However it will be compiled with clang so if an issue look at the port to see how the porter dealt with this - as this is a compile time issue I doubt you get into differences with clang and gcc use of stdlib

Comment: I had the same error.

Check it here a possible solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983919/error-while-make-on-mac-mavericks-the-3-0-beta

Answer (score 2):

So I'm a bit late, and with new problems to solve anyway.
My issues was that my main folder which contained the binaries had a space in the name.
And ocl has issues with those.

I removed the space and it built smoothly.

I did NOT expect this.